# How to parse nested json fields in list into dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

I am making API calls and getting back nested JSON response for every ID.

If I run the API call for one ID the JSON looks like this.

```
u'{"id":26509,"name":"ORD.00001","order_type":"sales","consumer_id":415372,"order_source":"in_store","is_submitted":0,"fulfillment_method":"in_store","order_total":150,"balance_due":150,"tax_total":0,"coupon_total":0,"order_status":"cancelled","payment_complete":null,"created_at":"2017-12-02 19:49:15","updated_at":"2017-12-02 20:07:25","products":[{"id":48479,"item_master_id":239687,"name":"QA_FacewreckHaze","quantity":1,"pricing_weight_id":null,"category_id":1,"subcategory_id":8,"unit_price":"150.00","original_unit_price":"150.00","discount_total":"0.00","created_at":"2017-12-02 19:49:45","sold_weight":10,"sold_weight_uom":"GR"}],"payments":[],"coupons":[],"taxes":[],"order_subtotal":150}'
```

I can successfully parse this one JSON string into a dataframe using this line of code:

```
order_detail = json.loads(r.text)
order_detail = json_normalize(order_detail_staging)
```

I can iterate all my IDs through the API using this code:

```
lists = []

for id in df.id:
       r = requests.get("URL/v1/orders/{id}".format(id=id), headers = headers_order)
       lists.append(r.text)
```

Now that all my JSON responses are stored in the list. How do I write all the elements into the list into a dataframe?

The code I have been trying is this:

```
for x in lists:
    order_detail = json.loads(x)
    order_detail = json_normalize(x)
    print(order_detail)
```

I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'itervalues'
```

I know this is happening at line:

```
order_detail = json_normalize(x)
```

Why does this line work for a single JSON string but not for the list? What can I do get the list of nested JSON into a dataframe?

Thank you in advance for the help.

edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-108-5051d2ceb18b>", line 3, in <module>
    for id in df.id

  File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 802, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-108-5051d2ceb18b>", line 3, in <module>
    for id in df.id

  File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 802, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use response .json() method
- feed it directly to `json_normalize`

Example:

```
df = json_normalize([
    requests.get("URL/v1/orders/{id}".format(id=id), headers = headers_order).json()
    for id in df.id
])
```

#### UPD:

failsaife version to handle incorrect responses:

```
def gen():
    for id in df.id:
        try:
            yield requests.get("URL/v1/orders/{id}".format(id=id), headers = headers_order).json()
        except ValueError:  # incorrect API response
            pass

df = json_normalize(list(gen()))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Marat. I tried your line and got the error. 'ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded'

Comment: is it raised by pandas or requests?

Comment: so it is raised by requests, because the API returns invalid JSON. I edited the answer to account for this, assuming it is safe to ignore such responses,

Comment: Wow that worked! Could you please tell me how you knew it was an issue by requests?

Comment: if you look at the stack trace, the first line after your code says is `File "/Users/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py"` - i.e. everything below is inside requests

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [28]: lst = list(set(order_detail) - set(['products','coupons','payments','taxes']))

In [29]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(order_detail, ['products'], lst, meta_prefix='p_')
Out[29]:
   category_id           created_at discount_total     id  item_master_id              name original_unit_price pricing_weight_id  \
0            1  2017-12-02 19:49:45           0.00  48479          239687  QA_FacewreckHaze              150.00              None

   quantity  sold_weight         ...          p_tax_total  p_order_source p_consumer_id p_payment_complete p_coupon_total  \
0         1           10         ...                    0        in_store        415372               None              0

   p_fulfillment_method  p_order_type p_is_submitted  p_balance_due         p_updated_at
0              in_store         sales              0            150  2017-12-02 20:07:25

[1 rows x 29 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I get the error, TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int64 found